# Transparent black gradient shape drawable color code

Tags: android, gradient, shapes, android-drawable

[image: gradient for view pager indicator]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#000"
        android:centerColor="#00000000"
        android:endColor="#000"
        android:angle="270"
        android:dither="true"
     />
</shape>
```

This is the code I tried but it ends up as pure black.

Comment: You misspelt Butler. Somebody clearly doesn't have one! *scoff scoff*

Answer (score 55, accepted):

What about this gradient? Full transparency at top to 50% transparent black at bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:endColor="#80000000"
        android:angle="270"
        android:dither="true"
     />
</shape>
```

Comment: yup,,tatz d one i was looking for.

Comment: @MD Glad that it helped you! ;)

Comment: you are awesome. I was looking for it

Comment: @NaveedAhmad Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:endColor="#FF000000"
        android:angle="270"
        android:dither="true"
     />
</shape>
```

Comment: Just change FF in endColor to any alpha value

Answer (score 1):

Add your class this code

> `GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
>                                   GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
>                                   new int[] {endColor,startColor});
>                           gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
>                           layout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);`
>   Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

```
In my case it works great:


   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:startColor="#000000" />
    </shape>
```